# MKCoordinateregion's center changes when span changed - iphone

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion

I have a MKCoordinateregion called region. I want to change span of this region without changing it's center. I am using following method to change zoom.

```
 -(void) changeZoom
    {

     NSLog(@"before zoom span, center are   %f, %f,%f,%f", region.span.latitudeDelta, region.span.longitudeDelta, mymap.centerCoordinate.latitude, mymap.centerCoordinate.longitude);
                region.span.latitudeDelta = current_factor ;
                region.span.longitudeDelta = current_factor ;
                region.center.latitude = mymap.centerCoordinate.latitude ;
                region.center.longitude = mymap.centerCoordinate.longitude ;
                [mymap setRegion:region animated:TRUE];

                NSLog(@"after zoom span, center are   %f, %f,%f,%f", region.span.latitudeDelta, region.span.longitudeDelta, mymap.centerCoordinate.latitude, mymap.centerCoordinate.longitude);
    }
```

Log shows :

```
before zoom span, center are   0.021950, 0.021950,19.068080,72.838111
 after zoom span, center are   0.043901, 0.043901,19.068040,72.838154
```

This method set's span accurately as desired.But I dont want any change  in the center's coordinate, Because when I zoom out and then zoom back I end up at a location different from starting location.

Is there any method so that zoom in and out are possible without any change in center?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your before and after center coordinates are almost exactly the same, so it shouldn't be a problem. If you really want the *exact* same center coordinates, call `setCenterCoordinate:animated:` right after you use `setRegion:animated:` and pass some saved center coordinates.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D originalCenter = mymap.centerCoordinate;
// ... adjust region
[mymap setCenterCoordinate:originalCenter animated:NO];
```

Also, you should use `YES` instead of `TRUE` for booleans:

```
[mymap setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the region of the map to make sure the aspect ratio fits the frame size of the map view.

Once the region with the desired center is calculated, adjust the region as,

```
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mymap regionThatFits:region];
[mymap setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:TRUE];
```

See [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205).

Comment: I couldn't find method adjustRegion: for MKMapView. have you used this method?

Comment: Oh did I use `adjustRegion`. I'm sorry - it's `regionThatFits`. The problem here was copy-pasting everywhere :)